# I'm getting empty object attribute when i use simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

When I'm trying to use `simplexml_load_string` it returns an array of "SIMPLE XML objects" with some "Empty" object attributes. Actually those attributes are not empty in the real XML output!

Do you have any suggestions?

```
    $url = "widgets.sportsevents365.com/data/tickets/v2.0/events/?q=cq,0,$sportType,$numOfDays&page=$page&perpage=$perpage";

    $ch = curl_init();     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER ,array('Contect-Type:text/xml','application/xml') );        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "*****:*****");  
    $result = curl_exec($ch);  

    curl_close($ch);  


    $xmldata = simplexml_load_string($result);

    print_r( $xmldata );
```

Comment: nop, not this what i meant :(, i tried that

Comment: suggest you var dump $result to make sure you are getting the full XML you expect.

Comment: oh i checked it , im getting values inside <![CDATA[ , then the simplexml_load_string is removig them, so how to catch those values ?

Comment: PHP will never assume that a file path is a URL unless it starts with a proper protocol prefix. Seriously. Whatever, you do two entirely different tasks (download a remote a file + parse XML) but treat them as a whole. You need to do some basic debugging: if file downloads OK, the curl code is irrelevant. If it doesn't, the XML code is irrelevant.

Comment: As you've discovered in your (now deleted) question, it is a good idea to assemble all the necessary information about a problem before asking. In the case of loading data into MySQL, it's worth saying if you are doing it in a console or a web application, how long it is taking, and what the reason for its failure is. Also, do check to see if the question has been asked before - that one almost certainly has.

Comment: Ok thx :) bro . I appreciate ur commment..and ur effort to keep Stackoverflow Usefull :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### From the comment...

> im getting values inside `<![CDATA[` , then the simplexml_load_string
>   is removig them, so how to catch those values ?

You need to use the `LIBXML_NOCDATA` flag.

```
$xmldata = simplexml_load_string($result,LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

---

#### Why to use `LIBXML_NOCDATA` ?

By using this flag it will merge the `CDATA` as text nodes.